# Decent tools for decoding images

Tags: image, encoding, image-manipulation, gimp

I have a HEX dump which I'm told is a PNG file and hence want to convert it into the PNG so I can view/manipulate appropriately.

I've searched all over the internet but can't find any good tools out there to do this.  I was perhaps thinking a plugin for GIMP or otherwise?

I'd love your suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by a hex dump?  Is it a text file with hexadecimal representations of all the bytes of a binary PNG?  Otherwise, are you sure you don't just need to add the .png extension to it and open it with an editor such as GIMP?

Comment: I believe it is base64 encoded but I obviously won't know until I try to decode

Comment: put the beggining of your data i8n your question - we can come up with a solution. Some interactive data massaging from a Python interpreter can give you your file, but we need to see the data to have you a recipe. And if you get several of thse files, that coulkd indeed be promoted to a gimp plug-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe it is just a Base64 encoding, try uploading it to http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp (first Google result for "base64 decoder upload"), choosing the options to decode, and export to a binary file.

Otherwise, if you could post a portion of the file in question, that would be of much assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).
Is not a GUI, but has a lot of features as format conversions.

Tell us which OS are you using.